# How to know the current space nodeRef in Alfresco?

Tags: java, alfresco

I'm developing an Alfresco app in Alfresco Explorer. In this app I create a Space and some content inside it, my question is how to get the space nodeRef when i'm working in a java class inside to list the contents.

Actually I'm trying this:

```
String nodeId = this.navigator.getCurrentNodeId();
NodeRef parentNodeRef = new NodeRef(Repository.getStoreRef(), nodeId);
List<ChildAssociationRef> children = this.nodeService.getParentAssocs(parentNodeRef);
```

But Returns `null`

Comment: Just a note that you shouldn't be starting new projects on Alfresco Explorer unless there are circumstances beyond your control that require you to do so. Use Alfresco Share instead.

Comment: I have no choice, client wants it in Alfresco Explorer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the following:

```
ChildAssociationRef car = this.nodeService.getPrimaryParent(parentNodeRef);
NodeRef parentNode = car.getParentRef();
```

Comment: `this.nodeService.getPrimaryParent(parentNodeRef);` returns `null`

Comment: what's the path of your parentNodeRef? This can only happen if your node is a root-node or maybe if your createNode transaction is not committed

Comment: @alfrescian: thanks for the comment ;). You could copy your nodeRef in the Alfresco nodebrowser and provide a screenshot of the details.

Comment: Finally this is the real solution but i forgot put getters and setters of nodeService.